# como fazer que a função siga uma sequência?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fnum_aleatorio():
    a=22695477
    b=1
    m=2**32 
    semente=3
    num= semente 
    num_aleatorio = (num*a + b)%m  
    if num_aleatorio <= m//2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

eu tenho essa função, quero que ela me retorne 0 ou 1 dependendo do número aleatório criado. eu tenho `a, b, semente e m` como parâmetros fixos! eu to tentando fazer uma sequência de números aleatórios pelo método da congruências lineares. ou seja, meu `num_aleatorio` deveria ficar mudando. teoricamente, essa função deveria criar uma sequencia logica que acompanha `num_aleatorio = (num*a + b)%m` ,mas eu não to sabendo fazer isso. tipo, da próxima vez que eu chamasse a função, o `num` se tornaria o `num_aleatório` antigo

Comment: O que exatamente você espera fazer com a função? Você comenta que o retorno depende do número aleatório criado, mas o número não é aleatorio. Tem como descrever qual é o problema que retende solucionar com esta função, pois, talvez, seja um caso de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878).

Comment: então, eu tenho a, b, semente e m como parâmetros fixos! eu to tentando fazer uma sequencia de números aleatórios pelo método da congruências lineares. ou seja, meu num aleatório deveria ficar mudando, mas não to sabendo fazer isso! teoricamente, essa função deveria criar uma sequencia logica que acompanha num_aleatorio = (num*a + b)%m ,mas eu não to sabendo fazer isso. tipo, da próxima vez que eu chamasse a função, o num se tornaria o num_aleatório antigo

Answer (score -1):

Transforme esses números para parâmetros e passe números aleatórios sempre que chamar a função, se você colocar os mesmo números sempre irá retorna a mesma coisa, eu aconselho a pegar a hora do sistema para gerar números aleatórios mas como não sei oque esta construindo não dei o exemplo:

```
def fnum_aleatorio(int a, in b, int semente):
m=2**32 
num_aleatorio = (semente*a + b)%m  
if num_aleatorio <= m//2:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

Lembre-se de sempre mudar os números que você passa no parâmetro, coloca num for e faça os números aumentar ou diminuir, faça de alguma forma que os parâmetros mude de valor.

Comment: então, eu tenho a, b, semente e m como parâmetros fixos! eu to tentando fazer uma sequencia de números aleatórios pelo método da congruências lineares. ou seja, meu num aleatório deveria ficar mudando, mas não to sabendo fazer isso!

Comment: pelo menos corrija o código de forma que seja Python válido.

Comment: meu, eu acabei de começar, eu to bem perdido em relação a linguagem. to aqui pra aprender. como eu posso deixar o código de forma que seja valido em Python?